# SQL query in unix shell script

Tags: unix

I have written a code that will give me the required output after executing it.

Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

sqlplus / << !EOF!
set verify off
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set feedback off;

select * from account where account_name='23553558101';

exit;
!EOF!`
```

The problem is that I'm getting all the non-required stuffs too, but I need the output only not other things along with that.

Below is the output I'm getting:

```
$ ./sqltest

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon May 29 17:32:52 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining Scoring Engine and Real Application Testing options

17:32:52 OPS$SP1ITA1B@SVITPRD1 > 17:32:52 OPS$SP1ITA1B@SVITPRD1 > 17:32:52 OPS$SP1ITA1B@SVITPRD1 > 17:32:52 OPS$SP1ITA1B@SVITPRD1 > 17:32:52 OPS$SP1ITA1B@SVITPRD1 > 17:32:52 OPS$SP1ITA1B@SVITPRD1 >   56566309 23553558101                      20-05-2017 05:41:00         57194135        20000184           64,56
20-05-2017 00:00:00  340393871           338845845          500               0
                      0

17:32:52 OPS$SP1ITA1B@SVITPRD1 > 17:32:52 OPS$SP1ITA1B@SVITPRD1 > Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining Scoring Engine and Real Application Testing options
```

Comment: it's not entirely clear what you mean by non-required stuff but i'm guessing the oracle connection info so if that's the case, you just need need to call "sqlplus -s /" to make a silent sql connection

Comment: I've written below code: #!/bin/ksh

sqlplus -s /nolog << !EOF!

set heading off
set trimout on
set echo off
set pagesize 0
set feedback off

select * from account where account_name='23553558101';

exit;
!EOF!`
I'm getting below error:                                                                                                            $ ./sqltest
SP2-0640: Not connected

Comment: why is there a nolog part after your / in your call "sqlplus -s /nolog"?
From a sql perspective, you are asking to connect with no user using nolog as the password.  You can either connect "sqlplus -s username/password" or use the database password file "sqlplus -s /"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using sqlplus in a shell script is better to log in using the silent mode "sqlplus -s" to supress the login messages and also to remove the sql prompt "sql >".

Further more, you need to change some variables like:

heading - it will not display the  head of the query result(the name of the columns to be more precise)

```
set heading off
```

feedback - it will not return the number of rows after a query select.

```
set feedback off
```

verify - is used to display the values in case you have substitution variables

```
set verify off
```

The columns presented above are ON by default so it is better to switch them off if you want a clean display (just the result) and also it is mandatory in my opionion if the result of your sqlplus will be collected by a shell variable.
You can check the manual for more information about sqlplus system variables:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG060